# Did Jorge Borges write that it takes two to write a novel?

Tags: quote-source, jorge-luis-borges

Did Jorge Borges say that all great literature is filled with ambiguities and obscurities? That it takes two people to write a novel, one the writer and the other the reader. If so, could you source it?